# Perl Error while building openldap

Tags: perl, build, openldap

I am getting the below error while building openldap in OS 2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64.

```
perl_back.h:21:20: error: EXTERN.h: No such file or directory
perl_back.h:22:18: error: perl.h: No such file or directory
In file included from search.c:18:
perl_back.h:21:20: error: EXTERN.h: No such file or directory
perl_back.h:22:18: error: perl.h: No such file or directory
In file included from bind.c:18:
perl_back.h:21:20: error: EXTERN.h: No such file or directory
perl_back.h:22:18: error: perl.h: No such file or directory
In file included from init.c:18:
perl_back.h:21:20: error: EXTERN.h: No such file or directory
perl_back.h:22:18: error: perl.h: No such file or directory
In file included from close.c:18:
```

I have Perl installed on the system when checked with command `# rpm -qa |grep -i perl`.

Comment: Whether or not you have the Perl *runtime* installed is probably not that interesting. Those errors are about missing *header files*.

Comment: Ok.How you suggest I can get the missing headers.any kind of help would be appreciable

Comment: There's most likely a package for them, though I don't know its name. Google is your friend.

Comment: "OS 2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64." is incomplete or cryptic.  Apparently you are using a RPM-based distro, but which one  (`el6` hints at Fedora)?  Anyway, RPMfind suggests [`perl-devel`](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=perl-devel&submit=Search+...&system=&arch=) for `perl.h` and it seems to include `CORE/EXTERN.h` too.

Answer (score 2):

You should try this command:

> yum -y install perl-devel perl-ExtUtils-Embed